# Use Serilog to log to a different Log File per Id

Tags: c#, serilog

I am using Serilog in my ASP.NET Core which is fine together with the Microsoft Logging Extension. The application is starting different workflows. Each workflow has its own id which will be generated during application run.

Now each workflow is logging data into the global log and i want to log each log message generated form a workflow to a separate log file (e.q. [workflowid].log) as well.

From the documentation it looks like that adding files is only possible during logger creation. Any other ways to achieve this?

Comment: Yes, one logger instance per sink, like a file, as I know, but I'm novice in using Serilog. Thus you should need as many logger as many file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a wrapper for the File sink that filters the events passed to it based on some property. It probably wouldn't be too difficult, Serilog is open source.

There is a pre-existing library that looks like it may do this for you, [Serilog.Sinks.Map](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-map).